# What effect does taking radio towers have on weapon availability?

Tags: far-cry-3

Right in the beginning of the game, Dennis tells you it's important to take radio towers because you can get guns for free in stores as a result. He's awfully unspecific as to how exactly this works, though.

Does each radio tower you enable, regardless of location, make free your bottom-most not-free tier of weapons, or do specific towers make specific weapons free, or what?

Furthermore, does taking over the towers have any effect on which weapons unlock (but still cost money) or which customization options are available for weapons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a tower weapon unlock list [here:](http://www.gamersheroes.com/far-cry-3-guide-radio-towers-free-weapons-guide)

> Radio Towers reward you with free weapons and items and they also
>   unlock nearby Supply Drop missions. You’re rewarded with free weapons
>   based on the amount of Radio Towers you’ve unlocked, not by the
>   specific Radio Tower itself. This means that if you want a specific
>   weapon, you can just go for the quickest/easiest route to get there,
>   without having to do a specific tower the other side of the map. The
>   below weapons have been placed into categories along with how many
>   Radio Towers you need to get them for free.

**Handguns**

- 1911
- 6P9
- .44 Magnum – Requires 11 Radio Tower unlocks.
- D50 – Requires 12 Radio Tower unlocks.

**SMGs**

- Skorpion – Requires 2 Radio Tower unlocks.
- A2000 – Requires 5 Radio Tower unlocks.
- MP5 – Requires 9 Radio Tower unlocks.
- BZ19 – Requires 14 Radio Tower unlocks.
- Vector .45 ACP – Requires 12 Radio Tower unlocks.

**Shotguns**

- M133 – Requires 5 Radio Tower unlocks.
- 1887 – Requires 4 Radio Tower unlocks.
- SPAS-12 – Requires 13 Radio Tower unlocks.

**Assault Rifles**

- AK47 – Requires 2 Radio Tower unlocks.
- STG-90
- F1 – Requires 8 Radio Tower unlocks.
- MS16 – Requires 10 Radio Tower unlocks.
- P416 – Requires 15 Radio Tower unlocks.
- ACE – Requires 13 Radio Tower unlocks.
- Bushman – Signature Weapon. Requires 18 Radio Tower Unlocks

**Sniper Rifles**

- SVD – Requires 3 Radio Tower unlocks.
- M-700 – Requires 6 Radio Tower unlocks.
- Z93 – Requires 15 Radio Tower unlocks.

**LMG’s**

- PKM – Requires 4 Radio Tower unlocks.
- U100 – Requires 7 Radio Tower unlocks.
- MKG – Requires 14 Radio Tower unlocks.

**Launchers**

- RPG-7 – Requires 6 Radio Tower unlocks.
- GL-94 – Requires 8 Radio Tower unlocks.

**Specials**
 - Repair Tool – Requires 2 Radio Tower unlocks.

- Flare Gun – Requires 7 Radio Tower unlocks.
- Recurve Bow – Requires 3 Radio Tower unlocks.
- Flamethrower – Requires 5 Radio Tower unlocks.