# I want to spend more time stabbing and shooting, and less time climbing radio towers. How do I do this?

Tags: far-cry-3

I'm looking to start a new game with Far Cry 3 again, but the thought of having to tediously climb those radio towers *again*, to get the [free weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95274/what-effect-does-taking-radio-towers-have-on-weapon-availability/95275) and show parts of the map are discouraging me.

**Are there methods* to skip climbing and activating the radio towers, and have them automatically activated?**

* PC mods, configuration file settings editing, cheats, trainers, etc., that will effectively make the radio towers activated, without me having to climb them

I will be playing on the PC.

Research update: I'm currently scouring [forum threads like this one (*Mods for Far Cry 3*) in the Ubisoft forums](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/734046-Mods-for-Far-Cry-3) and the [Far Cry Nexus website](http://farcry.nexusmods.com/) for possible mods that can do this.

Comment: @kotekzot About your removal of the [PC] tag, I included it as mods, configuration settings edits and trainers can only be used on the PC. And I am talking about playing on the PC version.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/questions-where-op-has-mentioned-he-she-is-using-a-specific-platform-how-to-ans

Comment: @kotekzot I am well aware of that meta question, since *I* asked it. I don't think it applies here, as I am specifically asking for solutions that are only available in the PC platform. I will allow the removal of [pc], if it can be proved that mods, configuration file settings edits and trainers can also be used on consoles. Also, please take note of the "always respect the original author" guideline when editing, before editing my question again.

Comment: SE is about questions that help everybody, not just you. Why are you so averse to the possibility of answers that will help people in a similar situation?

Comment: @kotekzot You are misrepresenting my position. It's about proper tagging of my question, not being "*averse to the possibility of answers that will help people*". I really wish that the "*always respect the original author*" editing guideline be respected in this case, but it seems that it is being disregarded. Like I said before, what I'm asking for: mods, configuration file settings editing, trainers, etc. are only available for the PC. Hence, my question is *specific* to the PC, and hence, the [pc] tag. I'm pretty sure that it will help other people, regardless of the tag.

Comment: The problem you have applies to every platform, ergo this question should not be tagged with a platform tag.

Comment: +1 with @galacticninja. Rather than adding [`cheats`] and [`mods`] tags using [`pc`] tag is more appropriate as this is pc specific question. Or you can just using the tags all together.

Comment: This comment thread makes interesting reading. Have an upvote @galacticninja for fighting 'the man' and being so gosh darned nice about the whole affair.

Comment: @galacticninja But this can also be a problem with the xbox or ps3. It is the same thing as the anwser with Skyrim and the console commands...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a mod like [Schwartz Mod Compilation](https://www.nexusmods.com/farcry3/mods/15).

This will unlock the second island, remove the Fog of War and allow you to  purchase all  the guns from the beginning of the game, even the Special guns.

This leaves very little reason to climb the towers in the first place seeing as the FoW is removed all over.
Remember to revert back to the original files you replaced installing the mod when you want  to go Multiplayer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any way to skip activating the radio towers, but there is a method to skip *climbing* them that I used a lot: just hang glide to the top of them.

For example, the glider located at X:654.9 Y:694.0 can reach most of the radio towers in the Northeast.

Comment: It's not really easy to hang glide to every radio tower. First, you have to get to the glider (even if you're nearer to the radio tower), and then somehow manage to safely land on a high portion of the radio tower (which takes time and is not an easy feat, based on my experience hang gliding to a radio tower). Failure to safely do so could: 1. have you land on a lower portion of the tower (meaning you have to climb it still) 2. completely miss the tower (meaning, you have to go back to the glider, or just climb it) or 3. cause you to die on landing.

Comment: Agreed, it's not a perfect answer, but on the other hand, you've asked a difficult question.

Comment: Hang glide -> Wingsuit -> Parachute should make it easier as well

Comment: +1 A really creative solution. This should be made into an achievement in the game.

Answer (score 2):

Their are some trainers that will teleport you to the towers with a press of a button. just make sure that you match the versions. i find that game copy world works the best. http://www.gamecopyworld.com/games/pc_far_cry_3.shtml. ow and you should not have to install any thing.