# Can you get to the south island early in Far Cry 3

Tags: far-cry-3

Far Cry 3 is a fun game, but it's even more fun with right weapons. [The Bushman](http://au.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-3/Bushman) is the perfect gun, but it's only unlocked after every radio tower is unlocked. It's easy to unlock towers, if you can get to them.

[image: Ultimate weapon]

Is it possible to get to the south island early? By early I mean before you get the wingsuit (2/3 of the way through the game)...

Comment: Related: [I want to spend more time stabbing and shooting, and less time climbing radio towers. How do I do this?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/103350/4797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're playing on the PC, try the **[Schwartz Mod Compilation](http://farcry.nexusmods.com/mods/15)**.

Some of its features that may be of interest to you:

- All weapons unlocked at start but you have to pay for them (note: towers will still give pop-ups saying you unlocked free weapons but you haven't)
- Wingsuit unlocked at start
- 2nd island unlocked at start

Answer (score 6):

No. Technically it's a matter of short swim from lighthouse ruin on north island, but the game won't let you do that until you get the "wingsuit" story mission in 2/3 of the game.

Comment: I have swum from north to south before with nothing physically stopping me. That was after I'd already completed most of the game though. What actually happens if you try to swim before the island is unlocked?

Comment: I tried to get to the south island early on by boat. First you get warning, then the boats gets turned back. Late in the game, I also swam from island to island without any problems (well, except some fisticuffs with sharks :)).